# error: 'l' is not a type

Tags: c++, vector, types, size

I'm programming in Linux and i have one problem. I have to initialize two vectors with size 'l'. 'l' should be given form command line.

This is code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sys/shm.h>
    #include <sys/ipc.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    int l, m, n, Id;

    struct vektori{
            std::vector<long double> a(l);
            std::vector<long double> b(l);
    };

    typedef struct vektori* vektor;

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
            if(argc!=4){
                    cout<<"Greska kod ulaznih parametara"<<endl;
                    return 0;
            }
            l=atoi(argv[1]);
            m=atoi(argv[2]);
            n=atoi(argv[3]);
            vektor v;
            Id=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(vektori), 0);
            v=(vektor)shmat(Id, NULL, 0);

            return 0;
    }
```

This are errors:

```
    procesi.cpp:14:29: error: 'l' is not a type
    procesi.cpp:15:29: error: 'l' is not a type
```

Comment: Why do you want `vector`s in shared memory? They can't be shared between processes.

Comment: The reason for the messages is that you're declaring two functions that take a parameter of type `l`and return a `std::vector<long double>`.

Comment: I noticed it now, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Add a constructor to `vektor` with `l` as an argument.
Use the argument to initialize the members.

```
struct vektor // Assuming you meant to use vektor, not vektori
{ 
   vektor(int l) : a(l), b(l) {}
   std::vector<long double> a;
   std::vector<long double> b;
};
```

and then, in `main`, use:

```
vektor v(l);
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I now attach memory segment to 'v'?

Comment: @VinkoCerovečki, are you asking about how to use `shmget`?

Comment: exactly, i don't know how to do it

Comment: @VinkoCerovečki, I am not familiar with the proper usage of `shmget`. I suggest you ask that in another SO post, with adequate details.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
struct vektori{
        std::vector<long double> a(l);
        std::vector<long double> b(l);
};
```

is seen by the compiler as an attempt to declare `a` and `b` as member functions. And `l` is used in place of parameter type. Since `l` is not a type, these member declarations are ill-formed.

If you wanted to declare `a` and `b` as class data members and immediately specify `l` as an initializer, you have to use `{}`-based initialization syntax

```
struct vektori{
        std::vector<long double> a{ (long double) l };
        std::vector<long double> b{ (long double) l };
};
```

(An explicit cast is added because of narrowing conversion.)

However, it is not exactly clear why you want to use a global variable to specify the initial size of your vectors. This is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your struct definition should just declare vectors, you look like you are trying to initiate them. on line 14 and 15 change `a(l)` to `a` and `b(l)` to `b`